# Why Sql execution delays sometimes?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, query-performance

I made my project in VB.NET with SQL Server as backend but sometimes SQL query execution delays even from SSMS.

I have the following query which I execute every time I want to fetch a product list:

```
SELECT 
    D.Prd_Code AS [PRODUCT CODE], 
    CONCAT(D.Prd_Desc1, D.Prd_Desc2) AS [PRODUCT DESCRIPTION], 
    D.Packing AS [PACKING], 
    Y.Company_Name AS [COMPANY NAME], 
    SUM(S.Clos_Stock) AS [CLOSE STOCK], 
    D.Scheme AS [SCHEME] 
FROM
    FAMPRD D 
LEFT JOIN 
    FAMCOMPANY Y ON D.Company_Code = Y.Company_Code
LEFT JOIN 
    FAMPRDMAS S ON D.Prd_Code = S.Prd_Code
WHERE
    D.Comp_Year = '2021' 
    AND D.Comp_No = '1' 
GROUP BY
    D.Prd_Code, D.Prd_Desc1, D.Prd_Desc2, D.Packing, 
    Y.Company_Name, D.Scheme, S.Prd_Code 
ORDER BY 
    D.Prd_Desc1
```

This query runs well every time.

But it's just randomly on any time slows down, and takes about 15 seconds to respond even in SSMS, no matter what the data is.

My client's average data in this query is approx 400-500 records. But the question is why it slows down sometimes and not every time. I have other clients who have more data in response than this one and they got no issue.

Probably it slows down once a day.

I suspected that might be my client's PC issue so I made him reset his PC and do a fresh OS installation. But this problem occurs in some other client's PCs too

**What I tried:** restarting the SQL Server from `services.msc` and it works fast for some 2-3 minutes.

Sometimes it results in a faster response after restarting SQL
Server but most of the time it slows down again.

**Solution:** I make the client's PC restart and it starts working fast again.

**Other details:** SQL Server used is SQL Server 2014 Express edition and Windows 10 OS

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). Then please [edit] your question to give us more information so we can help you better.

Comment: I've removed the vb.net tag. If the problem occurs also without your vb.net application, then this question has absolutelty nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MatSnow Yeah, I thought so that VB.NET tag isn't useful. Thanks anyways.

Comment: And, in SSMS, right-click in the query window, choose "Show Actual Execution Plan," run the query, and look at the execution-plan tab. It may suggest an index that will help your query run faster.

Comment: @O.Jones I am reading the link you give and updating my question as same.

Comment: @O.Jones Oh that I didn't knew. So what shall I do now. Wait for that issue to occur in my client pc and do as you mentioned and shall I keep the question for now or delete it?

Comment: @MatBailie I thought it maybe Query-based issue that's why I posted it here.

Comment: If SSMS suggests an index, and you create it, and your issue is resolved, you can answer your own question. That way others can learn from your experience. Still, give us your table and index definitions.

Comment: @O.Jones I didn't know about that. I definitely try in my client's pc when the issue occurs.. And shall I keep the question for now or delete it?

Comment: @O.Jones "Show Actual Execution Plan,"  - IS it DISPLAY ACTUAL EXECUTION PLAN? I am using SSMS. Seems like it

Comment: Sounds like you have some significant blocking going on.

Comment: @SeanLange As an?